# Problem with changing language with keyboard

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, language-support, input-language

I have enabled changing language in ubuntu 18.04 by keyboard(shift + alt)in gnome-tweaks. But now when I switch to language#2 by keyboard I can not switch again to language#1 by the keyboard. Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

That is what is happening exactly: I have two languages(English and Farsi). When language is English, I can switch to Farsi with shift + alt key but when I push alt + shift again, the language does not change and I have to change it by mouse.

When I enter `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` in terminal, I get: `@a(ss) []`
and for `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` command I get: `@as []`.

Thanks.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson 2 languages: English and Farsi

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson  Tanks, I edited my question.

Comment: The empty output of those two commands does not sound as Ubuntu to me... At least not the standard GNOME desktop. Anyway, based on your extended description I suspect that you use <Right Alt>+<Shift>. Try <Left Alt>+<Shift> instead.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I Tried that two commands in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Tanks, I was trying to change by right alt + shift, by using left alt + shift, my problem solved. Thanks a lot.